# Can I serve a hot soup recipe as a chilled soup?

Tags: food-safety

I make a spicy red pepper soup that is made with chicken stock. Is it ok to serve this soup chilled even though it has chicken stock in it. If I take it from the freezer, do I have to heat it first and then chill?

Comment: Why would chicken stock need heating? And can you clarify what kind of stock it is? Powdered broth, tetra pack, made from scratch? If from scratch, how? In particular, boiled?

Answer (score 5):

There's no food safety issues here, you don't have to reheat food to make it safe if it was handled properly before it was frozen. Just thaw and serve.

From a non-safety perspective if it's a soup that's meant to be served hot it will have a very different flavor cold, often being bland. You may want to test it out and tweak the recipe to make sure it tastes good.

Comment: One other concern: if made with a strong (gelatin-rich) stock, it may jell at fridge temperatures.

Comment: .. and even if it wasn't fully gelled, the mouth-feel may be affected: pleasantly or not, would be a matter of opinion. .. after all, consommé can be eaten chilled, as a jelly.

Comment: It could be a bit gloopy for sure.

Comment: likewise a soup that is particularly fatty/creamy may be unpleasantly rich or thick when cold